# Computation of Rees algebra of polynomial ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R=k[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]$, $k$ be a field. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ and $f\in R$. If $R[It]$ is known, how to compute Rees algebra $R[(I+(f))t]$? Is there any algorithmic procedure? It is easy when $I$ and $(f)$ are insect transversally.

Comment: What do you mean by computing?

Comment: What do you mean by $I$ and $(f)$ intersect (not insect, I suppose) transversally?

Comment: We say ideals $I$ and $J$ intersects transversally if $I\cap J=IJ$.